# How to run Specific function automatically or infinite times in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, label

I have Program in Python Tkinter in which I have made three rows of 10 Labels and a Start Button Below them. I have used for loops to display text in the Labels.

First Row of Labels only Display Headings.

[image: Labels Headings]

On Second row of Label I have set the condition that if loops value modulus equals zero `(a%2==0)` it displays Labels text ON else OFF and this condition is opposite in third row of Label as shown below and in the code.

[image]

Finally on start button I have called a function that reveres the process that if loops variable value modulus 2 equals one then display labels text OFF on second row of Labels else ON. This process is opposite on third row of Labels. And of this Process continues until i remain pressing the Button. But here, I want that when I press start Button It automatically remain changing the text. Code's Below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

win = Tk()
win.title("Label")
win.geometry("800x600+50+50")
win.config(bg='white')

label1=Label(win, text="Label Status Changer", font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), bg='white', borderwidth=1, relief="solid", padx=20, pady=20) #"flat", "raised", "sunken", "ridge", "solid", and "groove"
label1.pack(pady=(15,60))

list1=[]
list2=[]

lblframe = tk.Frame(win)
for a1 in range(10):
    pre1=Label(lblframe, text=("LBL",(a1+1)), font=("Calibri",12, "bold"), bg="white", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", padx=5, pady=2)
    pre1.grid(row=0, column=a1)

for l1 in range(10):
    if l1%2 ==0:
        list1.append(1)
    else:
        list1.append(0)

for l2 in range(10):
    if l2%2 ==1:
        list2.append(1)
    else:
        list2.append(0)

def mylabels():
    for a2 in range(10):
        if ( int(list1[a2])== 0 ):
            pre2=Label(lblframe, text="OFF", font=("Calibri",12,"bold"), bg="white", fg="Green", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", padx=11, pady=1)
            pre2.grid(row=1, column=a2, sticky="nw")
            #list1.append(pre2.cget("text"))
        else:
            pre2=Label(lblframe, text="ON", font=("Calibri",12,"bold"), bg="white", fg="Red", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", padx=11, pady=1)
            pre2.grid(row=1, column=a2, sticky="nw")
            #list1.append(pre2.cget("text"))

    for a3 in range(10):
        if (int(list2[a3])== 0):
            pre3=Label(lblframe, text="OFF", font=("Calibri",12,"bold"), bg="white", fg="Green", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", padx=11, pady=1)
            pre3.grid(row=2, column=a3, sticky="nw")
            #list2.append(pre3.cget("text"))
        else:
            pre3=Label(lblframe, text="ON", font=("Calibri",12,"bold"), bg="white", fg="Red", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", padx=11, pady=1)
            pre3.grid(row=2, column=a3, sticky="nw")
            #list2.append(pre3.cget("text"))

lblframe.pack()

mylabels()

def statuschanger():    
    if(int(list1[1])%2==0):
        list1.clear()
        list2.clear()
        for l3 in range(10):
            if l3%2 ==1:
                list1.append(1)
            else:
                list1.append(0)

        for l4 in range(10):
            if l4%2 ==0:
                list2.append(1)
            else:
                list2.append(0)
        mylabels()
    elif(int(list1[1])%2==1):
        list1.clear()
        list2.clear()
        for l3 in range(10):
            if l3%2 ==0:
                list1.append(1)
            else:
                list1.append(0)

        for l4 in range(10):
            if l4%2 ==1:
                list2.append(1)
            else:
                list2.append(0)
        mylabels()

#Button1
button1=Button(win,text="Start",width=10,height=2, font=("Calibri",16,"bold"), bg="black",fg="white", command=statuschanger)
button1.pack(pady=(30,0))

win.mainloop()
```

**Output on Running Program**

[image]

**Output on Pressing Start Button**

[image]

Comment: you may need `root.after(millisecond, function_name)` to run again the same function so it will loop and it will not block tkinter. `win.after(100, statuschanger)`

Comment: @furas But it runs only once but i want to run it again and again until i want to close it.

Comment: if you put `win.after(100, statuschanger)` inside function `statuschanger()` then it will run `statuschanger` again and it will use again `win.after(100, statuschanger)` which will run again `statuschanger`, etc. And you will have infinity loop.

Comment: @furas Still it changes only once when i press the button.

Comment: I don't know where did you put it but it works for me

Comment: did you use `win.after(100, statuschanger)` without `()` after `statuschanger` ?

Comment: I was using 'statuschanger' with '()' it but now when i putted it with '()' the program hangs.

Comment: `after()` (like `command=` in `Button`) needs function's name - it means without `()` - and later it uses this name with `()` to execute it.

Comment: if inside `statuschanger` you use `statuschanger` with `()` then it runs it at once and this `statuschanger` will run `statuschanger` again at once and it never returns back to mainloop. Using `after` it doesn't run it at once but it sends it to `mainloop` and it decides when to run it - and it has time to run other functions so it has time to get mouse/key events from system and send them to widgets and redraw widgets/window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `win.after(100, statuschanger)` in `statuschanger()` and it will repeate function.

```
def statuschanger():    
    if(int(list1[1])%2==0):
        list1.clear()
        list2.clear()
        for l3 in range(10):
            if l3%2 ==1:
                list1.append(1)
            else:
                list1.append(0)

        for l4 in range(10):
            if l4%2 ==0:
                list2.append(1)
            else:
                list2.append(0)
        mylabels()
    elif(int(list1[1])%2==1):
        list1.clear()
        list2.clear()
        for l3 in range(10):
            if l3%2 ==0:
                list1.append(1)
            else:
                list1.append(0)

        for l4 in range(10):
            if l4%2 ==1:
                list2.append(1)
            else:
                list2.append(0)
        mylabels()
    win.after(100, statuschanger) # run again after 100ms
```

Comment: Now this error is Generated: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__"

Comment: see my code again - you have to run it **WITHOUT** `()` - see `win.after(100, statuschanger)`. And it will not create recursion.

Comment: Love you @furas